# Converting RS-232 to I2C?

Tags: i2c, serial, rs232

I have hardware that communicates using 3-wire RS-232, and I want to communicate with it using I2C. Another post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/448060/rs-232-to-i2c-communication) talks about wrapping I2C in serial or vice versa. I am thinking about using an MCU to input/output both RS-232 and I2C as my conversion, and I am aware of the necessity of using a MAX232 or something of the like between RS-232 and the MCU.
Do I need to first convert RS-232 to serial like UARTand then to I2C, or can I put RS-232 straight into an MCU that then outputs that data over I2C or the other way around? Or does getting the MCU and the RS-232 communicating necessarily involve converting to serial, and if so do I need anything more than the MAX232 chip?

Comment: There are off-the-shelf solutions for this, if you are interested

Comment: Why do you want to use I2C?

Comment: typical MCU's have one or more UART's, so to get to RS232 or RS485 etc, you can get something working with just the MAXxxxxx chip that does it. I2C is for talking to a specific chip that talks only that way (often a sensor). It is usually a trivial task for an MCU to shovel the data back and forth. If there is no MCU firmware programming person at all, you can still get an off-the-shelf "i2c -> usb" bridge device, which will result in the host PC staying in the loop. A Raspberry Pi could be used also. IMO however the MCU solution is more versatile, b/c better control of timing in the firmware

Comment: Nexperia makes I2C connected UARTs and DUARTs, they should do what you need (also, add a transceiver to get the levels right)

Answer (score 1):

The MAX232 or similar is a line driver/receiver that converts between RS-232 signal levels and polarity and MCU UART serial port level and polarity.

USB will not be involved in your task.

Comment: So the MAX232 converts to UART for the MCU and that's all I need?

Comment: @InBedded16, Re, "...and that's all I need?" There's no way of telling what you need from the scant information you have given.

Answer (score 1):

RS232 is already serial UART prorocol. You don't need to convert it to USB or anything before using a RS232 level translator and connecting it to MCU UART pins.

Besides you seem to be wanting to convert I2C to UART, not UART to I2C. I2C chips that implement UART exists. Or you can connect an MCU to convert between those, or simply get a large enough MCU with enough pins to just use UART directly.